# Select all from tables where table names are from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2014

I have a temp table which has a TableName column. I would like to loop through the temporary table and select everything in the the table (where table is the TableName column in the temp table).

I have been looking through the following link and related links however I am unable to adapt it to my needs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2014

Something which i have tried

Declare @id int
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ##tt_tableList)
BEGIN
Select Top 1 @id = Id from ##tt_tableList

```
-- Do the work --
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = 'Select * from (select TableName from ##tt_tablelist where id = '' +Cast(@id as nvarchar(50))+'')'
select @query
declare @tableName nvarchar(50)
set @tableName = (select TableName from ##tt_tableList where id = @id)
select @tableName
execute(@query)
-- Scrap the ID and Move On --
Delete ##tt_tableList where ID = @id
END
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do that.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried and what errors were given? We can't really help without anything provided..

Comment: @Option - I have updated my question with what i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this is what you are asking for:

```
DECLARE @tbl table (TableName varchar(50))
insert into @tbl values ('SomeTableName')
insert into @tbl values ('AnotherTableName')


DECLARE @Tables VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Tables = COALESCE(@Tables + CHAR(13), '') + 'SELECT * FROM '+ TableName 
FROM @tbl

exec(@Tables)
```

Just insert your table names in @tbl

Comment: You understood me correctly.  I got it working see update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this based on answer from one of our fellow stack overflower and it works.

```
DECLARE @Tables VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Tables = COALESCE(@Tables + CHAR(13), '') + 'SELECT * FROM '+ TableName + ' Where Event like ''%CM_Manual_Change%'''
FROM ##tt_tableList 

select @Tables

exec(@Tables)
```